# Solving XOR matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i have this XOR equations:

```
(x1 ⊕ x2 =1)

(x2 ⊕ x3 =1) 
 
(x3 ⊕ x4 =1)

(x4 ⊕ x5 =1)

(x5 ⊕ x1 =1)
```

i want to show that i can transform this unsolvable matrix into antoher solveable matrix , for example if x1 ⊕ x2 =0 then the new matrix is solveable. but before i can do this i need to understand how to handle this xor equations.
i have a few questions about it.

1. what is the rank of this equations matrix and how to calculate it ? iam not sure how to handle this xor equations.
2. i know that this matrix is unsolvable , but why ?
   here is what i already tried, use a sequence of elemetrary row operations and then in each line there is exactly one variable with 1. but its mean that the rank of this matrix is 5 , but i think it 4.
   if someone could explain to me how to "take the sum of all the rows and observe that a nontrivial linear combination equals zero" it will be great.

Edit:
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&1&1&0&0\\ \:0&0&1&1&0\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\\ \:1&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&1&1&0&0\\ \:0&0&1&1&0\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\\ \:0&1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&1&1&0&0\\ \:0&0&1&1&0\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\\ \:0&0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&1&1&0&0\\ \:0&0&1&1&0\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\ \:0&1&1&0&0\\ \:0&0&1&1&0\\ \:0&0&0&1&1\\ \:0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
and in the last matrix the rank is 4 and its clear that this matrix is unsolvable

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: So you are trying to solve a system of equations over the field $\mathbb Z_2$. Check that $x\oplus y = x+y$ in this field.

Answer (score 2):

**First proof :** based on associativity/commutativity property of $\oplus$ :

By contradiction : Assume a solution $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ exists. Let :

$b=x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus x_4\oplus x_5\oplus x_1\tag{1}$

Using associativity of $\oplus$ :

$b=(x_1\oplus x_2)\oplus (x_3\oplus x_4)\oplus (x_5\oplus x_1)$

we get

$$b=1 \oplus 1 \oplus 1 = 1\tag{2}$$

But, as $\oplus$ is commutative (and associative) :

$b=(x_1\oplus x_1)\oplus (x_2\oplus x_3)\oplus (x_4\oplus x_5)=0 \oplus 1 \oplus 1=0$

Contradiction with (2)...

**Second proof :** (in a linear algebra spirit)

Let $M=\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&1}.$

First manner :

$$M\underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1\\1}}_{V_1}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0\\0}\tag{3}$$

Therefore the kernel of $M$ contains the non zero vector $V_1$ : as a consequence $M$ isn't invertible.

Second (equivalent) manner :

$$M \underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\1\\0}}_{V_2}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\1\\1}}_{V'_2} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ M\underbrace{\pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\0\\1}}_{V_3}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\1\\1}}_{V'_3}\tag{4}$$

2 different vectors have the same image : $M$ doesn't generate a bijective transform ; therefore it is not invertible.

Remark : If one adds the two relationships in (4) : $M(V_2+V_3)=V'_2+V'_3$, one retrieves exactly relationship (3).

**Third proof :**

Using a **truth table** (with the help of a computer program given below).

Taking  $y_{pq}:=x_p\oplus x_q$, see the result below : we can conclude because we never have $11111$ in the 5 last columns.

$$\begin{array}{|ccccc|ccccc|}\hline
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&y_{12}&y_{23}&y_{34}&y_{45}&y_{51}\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&1&0&0&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
\hline\end{array}$$

Matlab program :

```
 n=5;p=2^n;
 T=dec2base((0:(p-1))',2,n)-'0';
 xo=@(p,q)(xor(T(:,p),T(:,q)));
 X=[xo(1,2),xo(2,3),xo(3,4),xo(4,5),xo(5,1)];
 [T,X]
```

Equivalent Python program :

```
 import numpy as np
 import itertools as it
 n=5
 p=2**n
 T = matrix(it.product([0, 1], repeat=n))
 def xo(k,p,q) : 
    return(bool(T[k,p])^bool(T[k,q]))
 S=[];
 for k in range(p) :
    S.append([xo(k,0,1),xo(k,1,2),xo(k,2,3),xo(k,3,4),xo(k,4,0)])
 X=matrix(S)
 TX=np.concatenate((T,X),axis=1)
 print(TX)
```

**Important remark :** Do you know the existence of an online software called "SAGE" giving you (in particular) the opportunity to work in abstract domains like $GF(2)$ (order 2 Galois Field). Here is for example the little script giving the different powers of matrix $M$. Test it :

1. call https://sagecell.sagemath.org/
2. copy-paste in the "Edit" window the program below.
3. click on "Evaluate" button.

> ```
>  M=matrix(GF(2),[
>  [1,1,0,0,0],
>  [0,1,1,0,0],
>  [0,0,1,1,0],
>  [0,0,0,1,1],
>  [1,0,0,0,1]]);
>  for k in range(32) :
>     Q=M^k;
>     show(k,Q)
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. iam not sure why the above matrix is unsolvable. maybe you could help me understand this part please?

Comment: Thank you . much appreciated

Comment: I have added a second "manner" to have a linear algebra proof. I have also simplified the Matlab program.

Comment: Just added an important remark advising the use of SAGE software for such issues.

Comment: Just added an equivalent Python program.

Answer (score 2):

XOR is addition mod $2\,.$ When you add the first row to the
last row you get
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&1}\longrightarrow
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\\color{red}0&1&0&0&1}\,.
$$
Now repeat this with the second, third and forth row. The resulting matrix
has rank $4\,:$

> $$\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0}\,.$$

When we did this with the augmented matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0&|&1\\0&1&1&0&0&|&1\\0&0&1&1&0&|&1\\0&0&0&1&1&|&1\\1&0&0&0&1&|&1}
$$
we got a system that is clearly unsolvable:

> $$\pmatrix{1&1&0&0&0&|&1\\0&1&1&0&0&|&1\\0&0&1&1&0&|&1\\0&0&0&1&1&|&1\\\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&|&\color{red}1}\,$$ because of $1+1+1+1+1\mod 2=\color{red}1\,.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. can you please explain why this matrix in unsolvable ?

Comment: i think its because in the resulting matrix the last line is 0's and its equals to 1 so we have a contradiction ?

Comment: @ArkOnellea Don't click on the 2nd spoiler and work it out. There is also a much simpler way of finding that no $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ solves those equations. Just use all possible values of $x_1$ and let it run through.

Comment: one more question please, this xor equation: x1 ⊕ x2 =1 is equivalent to (x1 or x2) and (not x1 or not x2) . now if iam reomve this: (x1 or x2) . what heppens to the xor equation?

Comment: @ArkOnellea . The circus horse won't jump over another bar unless you edit OP and show own attempts.

Comment: done. can you please answer my question ?

Comment: @ArkOnellea What question? You just answered the old XOR question with a lot of help from me. If you have *one more* question I need to see OP edited with regards to *that*. It is time to enforce some quality standards here.

Comment: why are you so mad? is it bad thing that you helped me ? this is the question that i have : this xor equation: x1 ⊕ x2 =1 is equivalent to (x1 or x2) and (not x1 or not x2) . now if iam reomve this: (x1 or x2) . what heppens to the xor equation?

Comment: I am not mad. That new question I read in a comment already. Why should I answer it without having seen a clean formal question in OP plus your own efforts? It should take you only a few lines to unambiguously define what that new operation is. $x_1,x_2$ can be only $0$ and $1\,.$ Four combinations.

Comment: iam sorry its my first time posting a question here. i will edit my op but iam not sure what effort you want me to show?

Comment: Be precise with your definitions and creative with your efforts. The first item is the most important.